# Chainlink webhook job manual runs: jobRun.requestBody: keypath not found

Tags: chainlink

Running a [webhook job](https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/types/webhook/) to test an external adapter:

```ini
type            = "webhook"
schemaVersion   = 1
observationSource   = """
    parse_request  [type="jsonparse" path="data,result" data="$(jobRun.requestBody)"]
    send_to_bridge [type="bridge" name="get-sha256sum" requestData="{ \\"url\\": $(parse_request) }"]

    parse_request -> send_to_bridge
"""
```

doing manual runs with this input:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/018/012/this_is_fine.jpeg",
  }
}
```

getting an error from `jsonparse` task:
`data: key requestBody / keypath jobRun.requestBody: keypath not found`
A bit more output:

```json
  "job": {
    "__typename": "Job",
    "id": "6",
    "name": "wh4",
    "observationSource": " parse_request [type="jsonparse" path="data,result" data="$(jobRun.requestBody)"] send_to_bridge [type="bridge" name="get-sha256sum" requestData="{ \"url\": $(parse_request) }"] parse_request -> send_to_bridge "
  },
  "status": "ERRORED",
```

How should I do manual runs?
I suspect it's dev mode and webUI, but not so sure.
Running Docker image `chainlink:1.5.1-root`,
`"Image": "sha256:310e5b014dcc135e9fc2d9ca6c9367687f7579db5119c6b2dc556309847d5a47",`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `key path not found` because the chainlink node cannot find the key "`result`" in your bridge URI.

Change the path to match the nested key path within the json output of the bridge URI: `path="data,url"`